# Unexpected behavior with variable scopes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, llvm

I've got a crash with message "attempt to insert nil into array" in this code.

```
if (bookingID) {
    SBRequest *request = [[SBSession defaultSession] editBooking:bookingData callback:callbak];
    [pendingRequests addObject:request.requestID];
    [[SBSession defaultSession] performReqeust:request];
}
else {
    SBRequest *request = [[SBSession defaultSession] book:sbookingData callback:callbak];
    [pendingRequests addObject:request.requestID];
    [[SBSession defaultSession] performReqeust:request];
}
```

Crash occurs later on line 4 (inside of `performRequest:` method). Which means that `request` parameter is `nil`. But this also means that crash should occur on line 3 because `requestID` also should be `nil`. I've used debugger and saw this image:

[image]

Looks like I have two `request` variables and one is `nil`. I've solved the problem by renaming variables in if/else scopes. So, in some reason compiler creates variables in both 'if' and 'else' scopes. And at some point uses variable from 'else' scope in 'if' scope.

Is it a bug of compiler? How does variable scopes works in Objective-C?

Xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005). I use default configuration for compiler (Apple LLVM 7.0). No custom compiler flags except for language dialect GNU99.

Comment: Can you check what actually passed inside `performRequest`? Step inside maybe? Cause it is strange that in runtime NULL-request passed.

Comment: Unfortunately this is "floating" bug and I can't alway reproduce it. I'll try to investigate it deeply. I wonder if compiler optimization can be the reason. I also had similar problem with static variables in different methods in another project.